# How to force a query conditional?

Tags: wp-query, conditional-tags

There is a long-standing WordPress core bug ([#16373](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16373)) in which, if custom query variables are registered and present in the query string, the query will not set `is_front_page()` true, even if `'page' == get_option( 'show_on_front' )`. Full details are in the trac ticket, but the end result is that the front page returns an invalid page instead of `get_option( 'page_on_front' )`.

I have a certain use case in which I need to pass custom query variables to the query string on the front page (using a form to pass registered query variables, which are in turn used to filter Theme options - a front-end Theme options demo). The above-mentioned trac ticket was closed as invalid, so I need a work-around.

I can force the front page template easily enough, like so:

```
function themeslug_force_front_page_template( $template ) {
    if ( '' != get_query_var( 'foobar' ) ) { // Registered custom query var
        return get_front_page_template();
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'themeslug_force_front_page_template' );
```

However, the underlying query conditionals are not impacted. So any code dependent on `is_front_page()` being `true` (such as, say, a slider that only displays on the site front page) will still not render properly.

I have attempted to modify `$query` at `pre_get_posts`, but this does not appear to be working:

```
function themeslug_force_static_front_page( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if ( 'page' == get_option( 'show_on_front' ) ) {
            if ( '' != get_query_var( 'foobar' ) ) { // Registered custom query var
                $query->set( 'page_id', get_option( 'page_on_front' ) );
                $query->set( 'is_home', false );
                $query->set( 'is_page', true );
                $query->set( 'is_front_page', true );
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'themeslug_force_static_front_page' );
```

The query conditionals are not modified. Am I attempting incorrectly inside my callback? Is there a different/better way to force the query conditionals, in particular `is_front_page()`?

### Edit

Note that setting the `page_id` **does** work in the `pre_get_posts` callback:

```
$query->set( 'page_id', get_option( 'page_on_front' ) );
```

If I omit the `template_include` filter, the displayed page is, indeed, the page assigned to the front page; however, `get_page_template()` is used, rather than `get_front_page_template()`. So, setting `page_id` at `pre_get_posts` does cause `is_page()` to be true. But the aforementioned bug prevents `is_front_page()` from being set to `true`.

### Edit 2

Per @toscho's request, here's some query var code, for context.

Register query variables:

```
/**
 * Add options-related query variables
 */
function themslug_add_theme_demo_query_vars( $qvars ) {
    $qvars[] = 'demo_foo';
    $qvars[] = 'demo_bar';
    $qvars[] = 'demo_baz';
    return $qvars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'themeslug_add_theme_demo_query_vars' );
```

(Where `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` are Theme options - background, various colors, etc.)

How they are used is simply to add a filter to a Theme option - that part is out of the scope of the question, so I'll omit it here.

They are output on the front end via custom Widget. The Widget output is just a form. Here's an example of one of the form fields:

```
<h3>Foo</h3>
<input name="demo_foo" id="demo_foo" class="pickcolor"  type="text" value="<?php echo $foo_setting; ?>" data-default-color="<?php echo $foo_setting; ?>" />
```

Generated query string on-submit:

```
www.example.com/?foo=some_value
```

Comment: Can you add a simple test case, eg. the code registering the query var?

Comment: Sure, the query var registration works fine, and everything using it works fine - but I'll add an example for context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you check what part of [is_front_page()](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/query.php#L3605) is causing it to return false?

I could reproduce the problem by following the setup from the trac ticket. In my case inside this function the call to [is_page()](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/query.php#L3660) was returning `false`.

I guess this is due to using `$wp_query->set()` for `page_id` and `is_page` is only causing the `query_vars` to be changed, you don't change the "state of the query" itself.

I was able to create a workaround for this by appending this two lines to your code:

```
$query->is_page = true;
$query->queried_object = get_post(get_option('page_on_front') );
```

Which resulted (in my setup) in the page being correctly displayed on the frontpage (despite the query_var being present in the URL) and also `is_front_page()` returning `true`.

I hope this is helping you somewhat further.

---

If you look at the definition of the [WP_Query](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/query.php#L826) class, you'll see that there is a variable `$query_vars` and a variable `$is_page`.

The `set` function you used (`$query->set( 'is_page', true );`) does only set a [query var](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars):

```
function set($query_var, $value) {
    $this->query_vars[$query_var] = $value;
}
```

It does not change the state information that is saved in `$query->is_page = true`, instead it sets the query var `$query->query_vars['is_page'] = true`.

That is a bit misleading if you come from an OOP-approach and understand `WP_Query::set()` as a classic class-setter function - which it isn't.

Comment: +1. This is working on my end as well. Thank you! Can you explain "state of the query" a bit, in the context of `$query->set( 'is_page', true )` vs `$query->is_page = true`?

Comment: @ChipBennett Tried to explain it a bit more.

Answer (score 3):

I replied in that Trac ticket too, but I think the base problem here is a lot simpler than this.

You're hooking in demo_foo, demo_bar, demo_baz as "Query variables", but they're not; at least, not in the intended sense.

While the ?foo=bar string after the URL is often called the query string, the "query variables" are actually just variables that affect the main query. If you don't hook in a variable, it doesn't disappear, it just doesn't get read by the main WP_Query object.

And in your case, that appears to be exactly what you want. Your variables are theme options, they're not part of the main Query (which gets posts from the database). You're not using them to select what posts to display, you're using them to set theme options and such.

If you don't hook them in as query_vars, then they won't affect the main WP_Query object at all. You will have to get them from the main $_GET superglobal instead of using get_query_var, and you will have to perform proper sanitization on them to prevent reflective XSS attacks (using esc_attr or whatever is appropriate), but this should solve your primary problem by eliminating the code causing the problem in the first place, instead of adding in an extra workaround.

Comment: That certainly addresses my specific use case (and demonstrates why the bug report remains invalid) - but the underlying question was how to modify the query conditional. What happens to the `$query` object and its conditionals is...somewhat less than well-documented, and can still be a bit of a mystery. :)